# NextCloud as Oauth Provider

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, oauth, nextcloud

I've noticed that in some of the current versions of NextCloud that there is an admin menu option for adding Oauth 2.0 clients. Doing so gives you a Client ID and a Client Secret as you would expect as well as taking in a redirect URL. Now the question is, how do I use this. I have only found one single mention of it being used online, and that is [this](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/nc12-build-in-oauth2-client-authentification/14852).

I currently am using the Oauth2 proxy from Bitly off of github which can be found [here](https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy). My web server is Nginx and I am running NextCloud 12. I have another internal application that I host as well, this is run along side of an empty GitLab install and that GitLab install is being used as an Oauth 2 reverse proxy to authenticate through before getting to our internal software.

Any help or pointers would be great, this seems like a very powerful feature of NextCloud that has seemly zero support/docs.

To be a bit more specific I will try to better explain my current setup and what I would like it to look like.

***Current:***

I have 3 "subsites" if you will:

- GitLab: `www.site.com/subsiteA/`
- NextCloud: `www.site.com/subsiteB/`
- InternalSite: `www.site.com/subsiteC/`

User goes to `www.site.com/subsiteC` and is bounced to the login of GitLab at `www.site.com/subsiteA/`. Upon successful login they are bounced back to `www.site.com/subsiteC/`.

Similarly if you go to `www.site.com/subsiteB/` you are proxied through `www.site.com/subsiteA/`, however, the user will still have to sign in through NextCloud.

(Going to `subsiteA` takes you straight to GtiLab)

***Ideal Setup:***

- NextCloud: `www.site.com/subsiteA/`
- InternalSite: `www.site.com/subsiteB/`

If you go to `www.site.com/subsiteB/` you are bounced through `subsiteA` but that is it. In this setup there is no need to login to GitLab before logging in to NextCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Nextcloud has added a [section about OAuth2](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/14/admin_manual/configuration_server/oauth2.html) to its documentation.

You will need various bits of information both about your client applications and about Nextcloud. Here are the most important bits about nextcloud:

- Authorization endpoint: `SERVER/apps/oauth2/authorize`
- Token endpoint: `SERVER/apps/oauth2/api/v1/token`
- Profile URL can be accessed as JSON: `SERVER/ocs/v2.php/cloud/user?format=json` ([example output](https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/5694#issuecomment-314761326))
- Profile information is then stored in `ocs.data.id`, `ocs.data.display-name`, `ocs.data.email` and a few others.

I wrote two howtos:

- [How to use HedgeDoc (client) with Nextcloud (provider)](https://docs.hedgedoc.org/guides/auth/nextcloud/)
- [How to use GitLab (client) with Nextcloud (provider)](https://www.claudiuscoenen.de/2018/10/oauth2-with-nextcloud-provider-and-gitlab-client/)

Perhaps those are a good start for your configuration needs. If you encounter any other good tutorials, make sure to mention them in the comments!